# Graphing difference of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graphing-functions, relations

Question:

Let $ S = (-10,10) \times (-10,10)$

Let $ \ T\ =\ \left\{\left(x,y\right):\ x^2+y^2\le 100\right\}$

Graph $S-T$

My attempt:

[image]

This is my attempt. I am not sure if it is correct. Will the boundary of the circle be included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost correct.

You just have to remove the boundary of the circle as they are in the set $T$ which are to be removed by definition of $S-T$.

Comment: How about now? Please look at the updated one.

Comment: seems fine for a sketch.